# VB.net publishing forms

Tags: vb.net

I know how to publish simple forms or a simple web browser made in vb.net. I made a gecko base web browser and then I publish this, when I executed the file I got some errors

Here is the error:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'xpcom': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Skybound.Gecko.Xpcom.NS_InitXPCOM2(IntPtr& serviceManager, Object binDirectory, nsIDirectoryServiceProvider appFileLocationProvider)
   at Skybound.Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(String binDirectory)
   at Skybound.Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize()
   at Skybound.Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at Skybound.Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Registrar System
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Administrator/Local%20Settings/Apps/2.0/JBP6A35Q.8PZ/ZRE7WGQ1.O1O/regi..tion_52bfd852927888ac_0001.0000_afb460d07594d782/Registrar%20System.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
Skybound.Gecko
    Assembly Version: 1.9.1.0
    Win32 Version: 1.9.1.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Administrator/Local%20Settings/Apps/2.0/JBP6A35Q.8PZ/ZRE7WGQ1.O1O/regi..tion_52bfd852927888ac_0001.0000_afb460d07594d782/Skybound.Gecko.DLL
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:


    


When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

What is the problem on this? Please help me make my file as executable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'xpcom'

Your program has a dependency on unmanaged DLL(s), the ones that implement the browser.  Visual Studio cannot find these dependencies automatically.  Xpcom.dll is indeed one of the components that get used in Firefox.  There are probably some additional ones.

You need to find the deployment instructions for the gecko library you are using.  To get these DLLs published, use Project + Add Existing Item and navigate to the DLL.  The Build Action property for the item should be set to "Content", it is by default.